# No version name next to user review on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, review

There are some user reviews that doesn't have the version name of the app specified. What could this mean?

Comment: I have the same issue, but in crashes and ANRs where it says app version 0.0 when there is no such version

Comment: You should post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment so here is a theory in form of an answer.
I think this might be the case of users installing your app from somewhere else e.g. from an apk file someone send them after backup your app from some file manager like EsFileExplorer or similar.